# Charge 2 form that has multiple one of plan amounts?

Tags: plugin-charge, stripe

I have been trying to set up a Charge 2 payment form and have it all working except for giving the user 3 different plan amounts at the end of the form.

For example, I need to offer the following in a select box or radio buttons at the bottom:

- Plan A at $10.00
- Plan B at $20.00
- Plan C at $30.00

This is relatively simple using subscription modal, but I only want it to be a one off payment rather than daily, weekly, monthly or yearly.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the docs here - http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/reference/payment-options and note this bit:

> planIntervalCount accepts int The number of periods for a recurring
>   plan. If you're creating recurring charge, this is required, and must
>   be 1 or higher. Not including, or passing a 0 value will create a
>   one-time charge.

So, you could do

```
<input type="hidden" name="planIntervalCount" id="planIntervalCount" value="0"/>
```

for a one off payment.

Comment: Hi John, yep this is exactly what I needed, worked a treat. Thanks for the reply